# Method to generate pdf from access+vb6 or just sql 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, pdf, adp

The setup:
Multiple computers using an adp file to access a sql 2005 database. Most don't have a pdf distiller. An access form (plain form, not crystal) is created that needs to be saved as a pdf.

The only way I can think of is send a request from access to the sql server for a web page. Something like: 
"http://sqlserver/generatepdf.php?id=123"

I'm trying to avoid the web page 'middle man'. Is there a way to generate the pdf in T-SQL? Anyone have any other ideas. I'm not looking for code, just methdology ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the form as a report, then use Access MVP Stephen Lebans free A2000ReportToPDF utility to convert it to a pdf file.

http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm

If they have Access 2007 they can download and install the free Microsoft Office 2007 Add-in to save documents as PDF or XPS.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4D951911-3E7E-4AE6-B059-A2E79ED87041&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251771(VS.80).aspx) client can generate pdfs natively.

It works inside of web pages and windows forms/wpf apps. You can programmatically trigger the export as well. The only downside is that you'll need to basically redo your form as a report.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I did not get it: you want to export an Access form and its data into a PDF file? Your form is basically graphics, not text, nor report. Do you mean that you want this form to be included as (for example) a .png file inside a PDF file or do you want it to be a full PDF file inheriting objects from the original form and allowing things such as text search and so on?